# Erlang / Erlmongo : Mongo arrays

Tags: mongodb, erlang

I can't find how to format my datas in Erlang and choose the encoding style provided by Erlmongo (default or mochijson) to be able to save datas as an Array in a Mongo document.

Example of a Mongo Document containing an array :

```
{
"_id" : MyId,
datas : [0,1,2,3]
}
```

This type of document is correct in Mongo format.
But how to create such a document with the erlmongo driver ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to build an erlang **property list**. Your example JSON document in mongo might look like this as an erlang proplist:

```
[
    {id, MyId},
    {datas, [0, 1, 2, 3]}
]
```

Try this out and let me know if it works. There are a couple different mongo drivers for erlang, and I think I've only used emongo.

Also, some advice that you didn't ask for: "data" is already the plural form of "datum". You don't add an "s".

Hope this helps.
-tjw